# Can't switch between 2 fragments

Tags: android

I'm building application with actionbar.Tab with 4 fragments.
I want to replace one of the list-fragments with other fragments by clicking on the first item of the listView inside that listFragment.

The xml contains only image and the list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/joFl" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/jo_logo" />



    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
    </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>
```

and the code is:

```
{
    case 0: {


        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ShultzFragment sf = new ShultzFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.joFl, sf);
        ft.commit();

        break;
    }
```

I've also tried to change from LinearLayout to FrameLayout but it doesn't show the imageView and the replace() works but it show the 2 fragments together.

Is there a simplier way to implement that?
thanks in advance, udi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by:

```
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ShultzFragment sf = new ShultzFragment();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, sf);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit()
```

thanks anyway